# Why can't I specify how a ko.observable should parse its value?

Tags: knockout.js

As I dig deeper into the concepts of knockout.js, I'm having difficulties to understand why I can't tell a ko.observable how to parse/write its value like so:

```
   dateValue = ko.observable({
        read: function (dateString) {
            /*convert a date string to an object here for internal storage*/
            return Globalize.parseDate(dateString, 'd');
        },
        write: function (dateObj) {
             /*format a date object for output*/
            return Globalize.formatDate(dateObj, 'd');
        }
    })
```

I'm aware that ko.computed's exist for this purpose, but they still require me to keep a "shadow" observable where the result of read() needs to be written to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write an extender to add a `formatted` computed observable so you may read or write formatted values while still giving you access to the "raw" unformatted value.

```
ko.extenders['date'] = function (target, format) {
    var formatted = ko.computed({
        'read': function () {
            return Globalize.parseDate(target(), format);
        },
        'write': function (date) {
            target(Globalize.format(date, format));
        }
    });
    target.formatted = formatted;
    return target;
};

dateValue = ko.observable('10/19/2012').extend({ 'date': 'd' });

// e.g.,
dateValue();           // 10/19/2012
dateValue.formatted(); // Fri Oct 19 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

dateValue.formatted(new Date(2012, 9, 31));

dateValue();           // 10/31/2012
dateValue.formatted(); // Wed Oct 31 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a ko.computed instead of ko.observable.  See below.   Observables generally contain only values or other observables.  Computed is intended for doing calculations

```
   dateValue = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            /*convert a date string to an object here for internal storage*/
            return Globalize.parseDate(this, 'd');
        },
        write: function (dateObj) {
             /*format a date object for output*/
            return Globalize.formatDate(dateObj, 'd');
        },
        owner: viewmodel.dateObservable
    })
```

Comment: This example will not work. The return value of a computed's write function isn't used.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found that [extenders](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) do exactly what I want, they can e.g. auto-convert values on observables as soon as they are set.

Comment: I'm curious how you can do this with an extender. Please provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it this way without an extender:

```
// dateValue() is the raw date object
// dateValue.formatted() will return the formatted date as well 
// as parse a date string and save it back to the observable
dateValue = ko.observable();
dateValue.formatted = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        /*format a date object for output*/
        return Globalize.formatDate(dateValue(), 'd')
    },
    write: function (dateObj) {
        /*convert a date string to an object here for internal storage*/
        dateValue(Globalize.parseDate(dateObj, 'd'));
    }
});
```

Comment: This example is seriously wrong. `dateValue` is the computed, so both your `read` and `write` functions would be recursive. Knockout will prevent recursion on the read function, but not on the write.

Comment: You're right.  I didn't spend much time thinking about it.  I've edited my answer to actually do what I'd originally intended...